# How to get auth error from sign in/sign up AWS Amplify?

Tags: swift, aws-amplify

I am currently trying to get what type of error is thrown when a user attempts to sign in/ registers but my switch case is not working because I don't know what enum I am supposed to compare to. Once the error can be determined the app displays a UIAlertController explaining the error. If I `print(err.code)` I just get an Int back. Can anyone steer me in the right direction? I couldn't find any docs on how to handle it.

```
func signIn(username: String, password: String) {
    Amplify.Auth.signIn(username: username, password: password) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success:
            print("Sign in succeeded")
            //Go to root vc
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Sign in failed \(error)")
     if let err = error as NSError?{
          switch err.code {
                
          case AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorType.unknown.rawValue:
                        self.presentAlert(errorTitle: "Unkown Error", errorMessage: "An unknown error has occured", buttonText: "Ok")
                        print("Unkown error")
          case AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorType.invalidPassword.rawValue:
                        self.presentAlert(errorTitle: "Invalid Password", errorMessage: "You have entered an invalid password", buttonText: "Try Again")
          case AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorType.tooManyFailedAttempts.rawValue:
                        self.presentAlert(errorTitle: "Excedded login trys", errorMessage: "You attempted to login too many times", buttonText: "Try Again Later")
          case AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorType.userNotFound.rawValue:
                        self.presentAlert(errorTitle: "Unknown Credentials", errorMessage: "No user exists with the credentials you entered.", buttonText: "Try Again")
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't worked with the iOS SDK (or Swift) but does this help? https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/d33aa1a2114cbbb82b6d98aa566468d72015de3e/AWSCognitoIdentityProvider/AWSCognitoIdentityProviderModel.h

Answer (score 4):

The type of error thrown by the Amplify Authentication library is an *AuthError* type, which contains a more helpful embedded *AWSCognitoAuthError* type.  The AWS documentation is confusing and misleading because AWS provides two SDKs at this time:  the [AWS Mobile SDK](https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/q/platform/ios/) and the newer, dumber [Amplify Libraries](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/q/platform/ios/).

It looks like you are using the Amplify Libraries.  If you break your code in the Xcode debugger on the .failure case, the debugger variable display shows `error` as `Amplify.AuthError` which requires a PhD in AWS to make sense of. But for purposes of illumination, if you slug this in under the .failure case

```
        case .failure(let error):
            if let actualError = error.underlyingError as NSError? {
                print("Cast to nserror:", actualError)
            }
```

you will get `Cast to nserror: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin.AWSCognitoAuthError.xxx` where the xxx might be `usernameExists` or some other *useful* error.  It turns out *AWSCognitoAuthError* is a straightforward enum which you can peruse by typing `AWSCognitoAuthError` at some random spot in your source, then right-clicking and choosing *Jump to Definition* in the Xcode popup menu.

I prefer to keep all the voodoo Amplify knowledge isolated, so I created a User class to interact with AWS Authentication services.  I include the error handling portions here in hopes it saves you some grief.

```
// At the top of the file, outside the class:
import Amplify
import AWSCognitoAuthPlugin
import AWSPluginsCore
import Foundation

// This typealias allows other modules to interpret error responses
// from the AWSCognitoAuthError enum, such as ".usernameExists" without
// needing to import Amplify everywhere.
typealias AWSError = AWSCognitoAuthError

// Amplify Auth methods return AuthError type errors, which are complex multilayer
// enums that require complex deciphering if you want to extract a simple error
// to guide the user.
//
// This custom Error type allows callers from other modules to receive a simple
// explanatory "message" string, which is pulled from the .errorDescription
// property of an Amplify AuthError.  The "error" optional is the returned
// .underlyingError property cast to an AWSCognitoAuthError type, which is an
// enum of all the possible problems interacting with Amplify Auth such as
// .usernameExists, .userNotConfirmed, .codeMismatch, or .codeExpired.
struct UserError: Error {
    let message: String
    let error: AWSError?
    init(message: String?, error: Error?) {
        self.message = message ?? "Unknown error"
        self.error = error as? AWSError
    }
}

// Example of usage, within the class.  In my case the class signIn()
// function includes an onCompletion callback parameter to allow the
// caller to inform the user and change the UI according to the results.
func signIn(username: String, password: String, 
            onCompletion: @escaping (Result<Bool, UserError>) -> Void) {

    _ = Amplify.Auth.signIn(username: username, password: password) { result in
        switch result {
            case .success(let signInResult):
                onCompletion(.success(signInResult.isSignedIn))

            case .failure(let authError):
                let awsError = authError.underlyingError as? AWSError ?? AWSError.userNotFound
                let userError = UserError(message: authError.errorDescription,
                                          error: awsError)
                onCompletion(.failure(userError))
        }
    }
}
```

In your view controller, here is how you might process the response from the example signIn() User class method above:

```
// Inside e.g. an @IBAction function
User.sharedUser.signIn(email, password: password, onCompletion: { result in
    switch result {
        case .success:
            // Go to root View Controller
    
        case .failure(let userError):
            if let authError = userError.error {
                if (authError == .userNotConfirmed) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowConfirm", sender: nil)
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: userError.message, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
    }
})
```